# Download button not working on mozilla firefox

Tags: html

I am trying to create a download button using html. The html coding I am using is

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="file_url" download>Download File</a>
```

This coding is working for google chrome which downloads the file. But in mozilla firefox, the file opens on a new tab instead of downloading it. I need the file to be downloaded when clicking on the button.

Can someone help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code that you tried to download file.

Comment: @Jitendra Yadav : I have added the html code

Comment: It's a behaviour of firefox, which can be changed in the about:config settings. The specific settings are browser.link.open_newwindow  and browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction

Comment: @Stuborg What firefox version are you using it seems working for me on version 39.0.3

Comment: @flauntster Could you tell me where I can change that

Comment: @Stuborg  just type about:config into the url bar :)

Comment: @Stuborg  for info on those properties, see:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction  and 
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow

Comment: I am using firefox 40.0.2

Comment: @flauntster I tried what you suggested. It doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Downloads work fine with chrome, but files get opened instead of downloading on Firefox and IE.